# execute javascript code only when an element with specific id is clicked

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to execute a block of javascript code when an element is clicked.

```
<a id="id-name" href="#">ABC</a>
```

I want to execute the following code only if above link is clicked

```
<script>
if(link-clicked){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng( 12.1223, 123.324 ),
    map: map,
    title: Some Location
  });
}
</script>
```

Note: just pure javascript

Comment: how can I know there exists same question already.

Comment: Search bar at the top? Google Search? Duplicate questions are marked as duplicate to keep the site clear and not spammed. Your question would redirect to already answered question rather than having a million places with the same answers..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `href` attribute to specify what code in javascript to run (ie the function to run). If you wish to keep the `href` you can also use the `onclick` attribute:

`<a href="#" onclick="myCode();">Click me</a>`

Here is an example using the `href` attribute:

```js
function myCode() {
  console.log("Run my js code");
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:myCode();">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is an event handler.

- **onchange**=>An HTML element has been changed
- **onclick**=>The user clicks an HTML element
- **onmouseover**=>The user moves the mouse over an HTML element
- **onmouseout**=>The user moves the mouse away from an HTML element
- **onkeydown**=>The user pushes a keyboard key
- **onload**=>The browser has finished loading the page

Using this type of event handler you can execute a block of javascript code when a specific event to a specific element occur.

EXAMPLE

```js
function myFunction() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('d1').value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="d1" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good option...

```
<a id="id-name" href="#">ABC</a>

<script>
    var $link = document.getElementById('id-name');
    $link.addEventListener('click', getPosition);

    function getPosition () {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng( 12.1223, 123.324 ),
       map: map,
       title: Some Location
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The onClick attribute is one option.

```
<a id="id-name" href="#" onClick="myFunction()">ABC</a>
```